# Variables Code Behind Cant Access

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, code-behind, protected

This is probably is straight forward.

I have a DropDownList and once a user click on an item I need to remember what they clicked before the DropdownList gets rebound so I made a variable outside.

But the problem is that variable cant be seen. The only time I managed to get it to work is using Public Shared variableoutside as Integer. But this makes it available to every page I only need it on this page I am running.

```
Dim variableoutside as Integer

Protected Sub lstTest_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstTest.DataBound
    if variableoutside > 0 Then lstTest.SelectedIndex = variableoutside 
End Sub

Protected Sub lstTest_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstTest.SelectedIndexChanged
    variableoutside = lstTest.SelectedIndex
    lstTest.DataValueField = "ID"
    lstTest.DataTextField = "testvalue"
    lstTest.DataSource = List_TestA.List_Test()
    lstTest.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields only live as long as the request. On postback you get a new instance of the Page class, so new instance fields.

A Shared (static in C#) field does live longer (entire lifetime of the application), but it's value is shared between all users of your site - probably not what you want.

A solution is to store that value in [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). That is designed for request-spanning storage of user-specific values. Note that the values are stored as Object, so you will need to cast back to Int.

**EDIT**
for instance, your code

```
Protected Sub lstTest_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstTest.DataBound
    if variableoutside > 0 Then lstTest.SelectedIndex = variableoutside 
End Sub
```

could be

```
Protected Sub lstTest_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstTest.DataBound
    Dim variableoutside as Integer
    variableoutside = Session("ListIndex") ' probably cast this to Integer
    if variableoutside > 0 Then lstTest.SelectedIndex = variableoutside 
End Sub
```

(note that I am guessing at the correct VB syntax, so you may need to tweak this)

And of course in the other method, instead of:

```
variableoutside = lstTest.SelectedIndex
```

use this to *set* that session value:

```
Session("ListIndex") = lstTest.SelectedIndex
```

You can remove that class field, as that's no longer used.

Comment: Thank you for reply, could you elaborate on how I would do that in sessions, clean version.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that is really cool. I like it, Thank you...

I changed it a little though and ditched the Dim variableoutside
and used the Session("lstTest") as my main variable. It remembers every time.

You have opened lots of doors for me, and now I can use them to remember lots
of settings for DropDownList,CheckBoxes, Textboxes.

Only thing I wanted to know is how many of those session variables are you allowed, as I am assuming that the sessions are using cookies and cookies have a max allowed per client and browser before that start overwriting themselves. At least this was true when I was using PHP back in the day.